# Access Stamen tiles flavors with OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, layers, tiles, html

I'm using OpenLayers (v2.13.1) and would like to use Stamen Toner tiles as background.

The example is simple to understand: http://maps.stamen.com/test/openlayers.html

But I'd like to use the ["lite"](http://maps.stamen.com/toner-lite/#12/37.7706/-122.3782) variant of the toner tiles, how is it possible with OpenLayers?

Answer (score 4):

Please check out the following code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>tile.stamen.com: OpenLayers</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.stamen.com/js/tile.stamen.js?v1.1.2"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map, layer;
        function initialize() {
            map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {controls: [new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher({})]});
            stamenLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Stamen("toner-lite");

            map.addLayer(stamenLayer);
            map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(-13630355, 4546576), 10);

        }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #map {
            width: 800px;
            height: 600px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

Found it !

`var toner = new OpenLayers.Layer.Stamen("toner-lite");`